# Gridview Itemtemplate DropDownList Enabled

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, itemtemplate, dropdownbox

I'd like the `DropDownList` to be disabled and enable it only after I click on the edit link on `Gridview`. As of now, it is showing the `DropDownList` to be disabled before and after edit link.

codes:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" Height="30px" Width="190px" SelectedValue='<%# Eval("FAQGroup") %>' Enabled="false" >
    <asp:ListItem Value="Most asked FAQ"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="Normal FAQ"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

aspx.cs

```
 protected void gvFAQ_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
    {
         gvFAQ.Columns[3].Visible = true;

         DropDownList DDL= (DropDownList)gvFAQ.Rows[e.NewEditIndex].FindControl("DropDownList1");
         DDL.Enabled = true;

         gvFAQ.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
         bind();
    }
```

Comment: Is that RowEditing event firing, and if so, what happens with DDL when you put a breakpoint on the line where you're attempting to enable the control?

Comment: Yes, RowEditing event is working. DDL highlighted is in blue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call `bind` at the end of the `RowEditing` event handler, the GridView is cleared and refilled, and a new DropDownList is created in each row. The control must be enabled after the data is bound, for example in the `RowDataBound` event handler:

```
protected void gvFAQ_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        DropDownList ddl = e.Row.FindControl("DropDownList1") as DropDownList;
        ddl.Enabled = e.Row.RowIndex == gvFAQ.EditIndex;
    }
}
```

Comment: How does this check for the condition where the Edit link is clicked?

Comment: @devlincarnate - It checks if the row is the edited one, with the `EditIndex`.

Comment: And can you explain why the OP's code isn't working?

Comment: @devlincarnate - I added the explanation in the answer.

Comment: I understand now, thank you for you help guys, really appreciate it! :)